# How may I run jobs every tot minutes?

Tags: bash, slurm

I'm new here and hope to ask the question correctly.

I'm working on a server that has **SLURM** as a scheduler. I have many samples on which I have to run a script, but to avoid overlapping the jobs and clogging the cpu I would like to start the jobs one after the other after two hours.

These are the resources I have allocated within the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=bwa                      
#SBATCH --output=%x_%j.log                 
#SBATCH --error=%x_%j.err
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2G
#SBATCH -n 128
#SBATCH -N 1                  
#SBATCH --time=10:00:00
```

And this is how I run the loop in the folder where the files to be analyzed are present.

```
for i in *bam; do sbatch pipeline.sh $i; done
```

**How can I add a command that starts the next job after two hours that the previous one is running?**

Any advice or suggestion is welcome, both for the resources allocated and for the way of running the jobs.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do this. Do you know the argument parser and parallel processing on the CPU in any language?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "overlapping the jobs and clogging the cpu"? This is  Slurm's main job so you should not handle that by yourself. A properly configured Slurm will make sure all jobs get exclusive access to requested CPUs. Note that in your case a job array would make sense.